# Vuetify validation just returns false and does not work properly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi i have a problem in vuetify validation.
I copied this validation from the vuetify document but still does not work properly.

`valid` keyword is always false, And i can not submit the form
here is my code:

```html
<v-form
  ref="form"
  v-model="valid"
  :lazy-validation="lazy"
>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="name"
    :counter="10"
    :rules="nameRules"
    label="Name"
    required
  />

  <v-text-field
    v-model="email"
    :rules="emailRules"
    label="E-mail"
    required
  />

  <v-select
    v-model="users"
    :items="items"
    :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
    label="Item"
    required
  />

  <v-checkbox
    v-model="checkbox"
    :rules="[v => !!v || 'You must agree to continue!']"
    label="Do you agree?"
    required
  />

  <v-btn
    :disabled="!valid"
    color="success"
    class="mr-4"
    @click="validate"
  >
    Validate
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn
    color="error"
    class="mr-4"
    @click="reset"
  >
    Reset Form
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn
    color="warning"
    @click="resetValidation"
  >
    Reset Validation
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

and here is js codes:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    nameRules: [
      (v) => !!v,
      (v) => (v && v.length <= 3),
    ],
    valid: false,
    city: '',
    address: '',
    disabled: false,
    creditValue: null,
    lazy: false,

    users: [],
    user: {},
    userID: -1,

    addresses: [
      { city: '', address: '' },
    ],


    errors: [],
  }),
}
```

Comment: In the `v-select` you say :items="items" but there aren't any items defined in your JS. Check your browsers dev console with F12, it should throw quite a few of errors that tell you exactly what you are missing. Same for the first v-text-field, it expects a v-model with the name `name`, which is never defined though.